# How to convert .net5 startup.cs code to .net 6 in program.cs file

Tags: .net

Please how can i convert this .net 5 `startup.cs` file code to .net 6 in `program.cs` file, i want to call the `dbInitizer.Initialize()` method in `program.cs`

Startup.cs

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IDbInitializer dbInitializer)
{
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    dbInitializer.Initialize();
}
```

Comment: If you review how Microsoft migrated the samples from .NET 5 to 6, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60-samples?view=aspnetcore-6.0 you can easily figure out where to put your extra statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two solutions that I found;

```
var dbInitializer = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IDbInitializer>();

dbInitializer.Initialize();
```

**Or**

You can call by creating a scope ([From asp.net 6 doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data?view=aspnetcore-6.0#configure-the-test-account) )

```
using(var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var dbInitializer = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDbInitializer>();
    dbInitializer.Initialize();
}
```